# Why does my standard deviation formula result in #N/A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the column entry for `A1:A24`

```
0,092
0,045
0,015
0,046
0,041
0,027
0,073
0,004
0,020
#N/A
0,000
0,001
0,004
0,000
0,032
0,000
0,002
0,140
0,005
0,001
0,251
0,001
0,061
0,023
```

I want to calculate `=STDEV.P(A1:A24)`. The answer is #N/A.

What is the correct formula, considering I need to calculate the standard deviation in one range? I don't want to write: `=STDEV.P(A1:A9;A11:A24)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=STDEV.P(IF(NOT(ISERROR(A1:A24)),A1:A24))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If don properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Enter is the thing